# Adding Password Protection to PDFs Generated with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, passwords, backend

I'm using NestJS with Puppeteer to generate PDFs in my Node.js application. However, I need to add password protection to the generated PDFs. Here's a version of my code:

```js
  async generatePdf(body: IPdf, functions?: void) {
    let pdf: Buffer;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--disable-extensions"],
    });

    try {
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      functions;
      this.formatDate();
      this.numerosLetras();
      this.formatCurrency();
      this.formatSpecialty();
      this.toUpperCase();
      const content = await this.compile(body.templateName, body.data);

      await page.setContent(content);
      
      pdf = await page.pdf({
        format: "a4",
        printBackground: true,
        margin: { bottom: 30, left: 20, right: 20, top: 20 },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    await browser.close();
    return pdf;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through a quick search gives me an impression that they don't plan to add this as a feature set [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6120).

What you can do is to use another library to encrypt the incoming pdf, something like - [node-qpdf2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-qpdf2). The usage seems to be simple enough -

```js
import { encrypt } from "node-qpdf2";

const pdf = {
  input: "./test/example.pdf",
  output: "/tmp/encrypted.pdf",
  password: "password_that_you_will_give_to_enduser",
}

await encrypt(pdf);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you might consider a more general approach that probably will provide stronger protection, encrypting the pdf with a separate file encryption utility callable from nodejs. There are many possibilities, but for example [Xecrets File Command Line](https://GitHub.com/Xecrets/xecrets-file-cli) is easy to use and would work well. There's also a
companion desktop app. In addition it's AxCrypt-compatible. [Disclosure: I am the author of Xecrets]

Answer (score 0):

The reason PDF passwords are only of use to a select few. Is that there are 2 levels of password and both store the decryption key in the PDF.

So what are they, and how to abuse them ?

- 1 is the so called "Owner key" this is the one you see that stops you from saving a or printing a pdf from browsers like drive by puppeteer, and generally can be ignored (it is optional and many browsers do not support it, but naturally Edge powered by Acrobat will!). So any app like puppeteer user is the "PDF owner" to do as they please, same goes for any other user you hand file ownership over to via a password to open.
- 2 is the more secure so called "User Key" this is the one somebody needs to see see and thus use your private data. Never give any body your private key to "open" a PDF otherwise they will become the owner of the PDF contents.

For this reason it is not necessary to provide passwords for impersonal PDF's, passwords are solely useful to protect PDF contents from viewing by others, much the same as an outer zip file password system, once opened the content is public domain.

If you get personal utility bills, banking or tax data with a "user" (personal) password it is easy to save the file without either password unless you wish to maintain your privacy.